# SQL Update table with select as filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to filter the selections of the table "Orders".. the table "Orders" has now over 40k of rows and if i want to use power automate i am running in a buffer issue so i want only update the orders in the "Order" table with a specific order status.. i have 4 order status that needs te be checked and that are

```
'processing_awaiting_shipment'
'processing_awaiting_payment'
'processing_ready_for_pickup'
'processing_awaiting_pickup'
```

Can someone please help my out with a WHERE function in the script below?

the script that i am running now:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders_Update_Status
SELECT * FROM Orders 

UPDATE Per 
  SET Per.[Bestel Status]=Addr.[Order status], 
      Per.[Totaal Prijs]=Addr.[Totaal Price] 
FROM Orders Per 
INNER JOIN Orders_Update_Status Addr ON Per.[Order ID] = Addr.[Order ID]
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Please provide sample data and a desired output. I am assuming that you are using SQL Server because of the syntax of your update statement.

```
UPDATE o
  SET o.[Bestel Status]=s.[Order status], 
      o.[Totaal Prijs]=s.[Totaal Price] 
FROM Orders o 
INNER JOIN Orders_Update_Status s ON s.[Order ID] = o.[Order ID]
WHERE 
s.[Order status] IN ('processing_awaiting_shipment', 'processing_awaiting_payment',
'processing_ready_for_pickup','processing_awaiting_pickup')
```

Comment: Perfect! that works exactly like i wanted :) thanks so mutch!